# Are there any bitcoin communities for women?

Tags: community

Not to knock the guys, but it would be nice to talk to girls about this awesome virtual currency...partly to bring awareness to enable widespread adoption of bitcoin, as well as to try to get involved with other girls who may be working on bitcoin-related projects.

Comment: Might be a great opportunity to start one!

Comment: I'm trying to teach myself about Bitcoin .... unsure whether I'd start mining though ;-)

Comment: I don't know why this is being voted as "primarily opinion based" as it's fairly clear that a factual answer can be made.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Meetup for [Women in Bitcoin](http://www.meetup.com/Women-in-Bitcoin/) in San Francisco. It might be helpful to try to get in touch with them as they might be able to point out a meetup near you or recommend an online community, unless you happen to be near there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [*Mädchenabend* in Berlin](https://www.meetup.com/Bitcoin-Madchenabend-Berlin-All-Ladies-Welcome/) for Bitcoin-ladies only.

> If you are curious about Bitcoin or already in love with it > and if you are a woman, you're in the right place! Since May 2014 we meet once a month in Berlin to chat about Bitcoin, share our knowledge, connect and -most important- have a lot of fun together! ---Girls and Women only!--- The goal of this meetup is not to entirely separate us from the male community, but to once in a while gather in a smaller, more pinpointed group and provide a space for exchanging our ideas and Q&A in a relaxed atmosphere.
>
> 'Every woman using and teaching #bitcoin becomes a full node that forms a World Decentralized Women Bitcoin Network. Steadily we grow.' (@TrueBitcoinGirl)
>
> To all our male supporters: Thank you in advance for acting as our ambassadors, spreading the word and inviting more women!